# Editing to Javascript function for animating html

Tags: javascript, jquery

So firstly I will admit I am a kook and have no understanding of javascript, I've jumped onto w3schools and tried to learn how to adjust the following however I have failed miserably. I understand that the solution to this question will not benifit the masses but it will sure help me, grateful for any advise.

The following script will animate the first `panel-heading` in an accordion list to the top of the webpage. I am however nesting many accordions inside one another [(can see example here)](http://stfstesting.xyz) so as you click deeper into the hierarchy the html will animate and the open accordion will be off screen at the bottom.

I need to specify the `panel-heading` of the opening `panel-title` and have that animate to the top instead of the previous or parent like what is happening now.

So I believe I need to change `prev('.panel-heading');` into current panel-heading somehow??

The script

```
$(".panel-group").on("shown.bs.collapse", function () {
    var myEl = $(this).find('.collapse').prev('.panel-heading');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(myEl).offset().top
    }, 500);
});


<!-- ACCORDION-->

<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="heading" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false">Panel Title 1</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Another accordion here and inside those panels are more accordions</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="heading" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">Panel Title 2</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Another accordion here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="heading" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">Panel Title 3</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Another accordion here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- END ACCORDION-->
```